# kNN algorithm predicts only one group

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, knn

I am trying to make a model that will predict the group of a city according to the development level of it. I mean, the cities in the 1st group are the most developed cities and the ones in the 6th group are the least developed ones. I have 10 numerical variables in my data about each city.

First, I normalized them using max-min normalization. Then I generated the training and data sets. I have 81 cities.Dimensions of training and data sets are 20x10 and 61x10, respectively. I excluded the target variable from them. Then I made labels for them as training labels and test labels with dimensions 61x1 and 20x1.

Then I run the `knn` function like this

```
knn(train = Data.training, test = Data.test, cl = Data.trainLabels , k = 3)
```

its output is this

```
[1] 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6
Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

But if I set the argument `use.all` to `FALSE` I get this output and that changes everytime I run the code

```
[1] 1 4 2 2 2 3 5 4 3 5 5 6 5 6 5 6 4 5 2 2
Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

I can't find the reason why my code gives the same prediction in the first place and what `use.all` has got to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the [knn documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/class/versions/7.3-17/topics/knn) :

> **use.all** controls handling of ties. If true, all distances equal to the kth largest are included. If false, a random selection of distances equal to the kth is chosen to use exactly k neighbours.

In your case, all points have the same distances, so they all win as 'best neighbour' (`use.all = True`) or the algorithm picks k winners at random (`use.all = False`).

The problem seems to be in how you trained the algorithm or in the data itself. Since you did not post a sample of your data, I cannot help with that, but I suggest that you re-check it. You can also compute a few distances by hand, to see what is going on.

Also, check that you randomised your data before splitting it into training and testing sets. For example, say that the dataset is ordered by the label (the target variable). If you use the first 20 points to train the algorithm, it is likely that the algorithm will never see some of the labels during the training phase and therefore it will perform poorly on those during the testing phase.